# How spiral torsion spring works?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics, potential-energy, spring

How spiral torsion spring (used in mechanical watches to store energy) works? physics behind it ? ... I googled it but haven't got a clue. Where should I look for proper and detailed info.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bend a spring (“beam”) part of it will be in tension and another par of it will be in tension as shown below.
The arrows indicating the variation of these forces across a section of the spring.

[image]

This deformation of the spring requires work to be done and that is where the elastic potential energy is stored in the coiled spring.

Making the spring bend more (winding up the spring) results in more elastic potential energy  stored in the spring as the compression and tension forces are larger.

Comment: Thanks for response..  how can we calculate energy?

Comment: @BilalQadri With great difficulty but there are articles mainly written by horologists which have references in them.  Here is one such article https://lespook.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/mainspring-7.pdf.  You might also look at engineering references about the energy stored in a stressed beam.

Comment: I'm very grateful for your effort. Now I have some idea.